# extract classes/ids from html pages

Tags: css, dom, html-parsing

I need to create a css stylesheet for an existhng html page. Is there any easy way to extract all the classes and ids using a script... I am familiar with python, java, c, javascript and php. Is there any library for those languages? re sems a bit overkill for me. grateful for any help.

cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to retrieve the `id`s of each of the elements is to simply iterate over the elements that have an `id`, and retrieve that:

```
var idEls = document.querySelectorAll('*[id]'),
    ids = [];

for (var i=0, len=idEls.length; i<len; i++){
    ids.push(idEls[i].id);
}
```

One way to cover those browsers that don't implement `querySelectorAll()` is to create a nodeList of *every* element, then iterate over that (quite probably very large) nodeList, test for the `id` and, if it exists, push that into the array:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    ids = [];

for (var i=0, len=els.length; i<len; i++){
    if (els[i].id){
        ids.push(els[i].id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using jquery, loop through the elements and get id and class

```
$('html *').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('class'))
})
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, wouldn't it be easier to simply retrieve those elements with an `id` to start with: `$('*[id]').each(/*...*/)`?

Comment: not if you want to find elements with classes aswell, maybe something like $('*[id], *[class]') would be better :)